# Stop Wordpress or Plugin Auto-scrolling on Product Pages

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Wordpress (or a plugin) keeps auto scrolling on the product pages... I don't know why.

Is there any coding I can add to stop this annoying feature?

Problem Example: https://roverplusnine.com/product/RPN-9999-115-FD/

Thanks in advance for any help....

Comment: Start by disabling all your plugins to see if it prevents this behavior. If it does, re-enable them one by one until the behavior begins again. Then look through the javascript included with that plugin and try to figure out what is causing it.

Comment: Any other way? This is for a pretty big company and going about it in that manner will cause site wide problems

Comment: Create a test server so you can test things before applying them to your live environment.

Comment: The problem doesn't replicate on the staging environment.

Comment: I see you fixed the problem. Could you share how you did it ? because now I suffer from the same issue

Answer (score 1):

In my case the culprit for this behaviour was the smooth scrolling JavaScript code I had added to my child theme. The solution is to not target product tabs. This can be done with a simple CSS `:not` statement. My final script also takes into account empty anchor links (the ones with just a `#`), and the scroll to top link, which already had smooth scrolling of its own in the parent theme. So here's my working smooth scrolling JS:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

// Smooth scroll for anchor links
$j(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]:not([href$="#"]):not([href^="#tab-"]):not(.cd-top)', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $j('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $j($j.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
  }, 700);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and found numerous others in my search with it too.

The common issue for many of us is that our themes have a smooth-scrolling script added for anchors, and regardless of our approach the tabbed description section of a single product page is targeted and scrolled to automatically. You can hide that section in your theme to test and see if that's your issue too with:

```
.woocommerce-tabs {display:none;}
```

That's not a solution if you have a lot of product description and need more room than the short description. If I find a fix for the behavior, I'll circle back. Or. Hopefully that'll be enough for someone else to go on to figure it out before me.